# readObject() is not working and breaks from method

Tags: java, object, serialization

I'd like to read different kinds of objects from file to an `ArrayList`, all of them are  instances of class which extend the class Advertisement. I'm trying with this code:

```
ArrayList <Advertisement> ads = new ArrayList<Advertisement>();
ObjectInput input2 = new ObjectInputStream(
    new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("ads.ser")));

//break from this method at this point
ads = (ArrayList<Advertisement>) input2.readObject();
```

The problem is at the 3rd line/last line. It doesn't read the objects in variable `ads` of type  `ArrayList<Advertisement>`, furthermore, it breaks from this method, without any messages.

Edit: Removed the try-catch block, I should have done it earlier, but I still don't know the solution. Stacktrace:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: Kiado; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1393576200767336208, local class serialVersionUID = -841663850423605586
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Main.beolvasas(Main.java:30)
    at Main.startup(Main.java:57)
    at Main.main(Main.java:633)
```

Comment: What have you serialized?List or an instance of hiredetes?

Comment: If it doesn't display any error message, it means your code catches the exception and ignores it, or prints its message or stack trace elsewhere.

Comment: I serialized the ArrayList.

Comment: Then `printStackTrace()` and let us know.

Comment: Create a SSCCE reproducing the problem: creating some objects, adding them to a list, serializing the list, then deserializing it and get the objects from the deserialized list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have a stack trace, the problem is clear: since the moment you serialized the objects to the file, you have made changes to the class `Kiado`. So the class you have now is not compatible anymore with the class as it was when serializing the objects to the file.

If you didn't change the number and the names of the fields of the class (and of all its superclasses), you can make it compatible again by just adding the following variable declaration in the class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1393576200767336208;
```

If you added, removed or renamed at least one (non-transient) field, then you might make the new class still compatible with the old one, but with more pain. And we would have to know the nature of the changes to help you.

I would personally avoid using native serialization for long-term storage because, as you just noticed, it's fragile and makes it hard to change the model. I would use a more easily readable and migratable file format: XML or JSON for example.

Comment: Yes, more fields are added to the subclasses. I am using serialization the first time, it seemed to be a decent choice. I'll certainly explore other options after I'm done with this project.

Comment: If you have only added fields, then adding the serial version UID should work, IIRC. You'll have nulls in all the new fields though, which might break the invariants of the class. So make sure that you handle null values for these fields correctly in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any code like:

```
catch(<WheteverException> e)
{
   // nothing here
}
```

If so do the following:

1. change the `// nothing here` to `e.printStackTrace();`
2. remove the try/catch and only add it back if the compiler tells you to, and then only add back what exception that the compiler tells you to add (for instance don't do `catch(Exception e)`.

Comment: Yeah, there was a try-catch block, removed, and added the stactrace to the question.

Comment: Did you make changes to your class(es) after you created the serialized file?  If you did then the serial ver changes...

Comment: Yes, but I rewrite the file after every changes.